# How to load data from allocated memory correctly?

Tags: c, function, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am new to C. I have a program that has multiple tasks like adding new patient, deleting one or loading data for a hospital. Within `choosetask` function I call the right one. My functions works well except ~loadhospitaldata()~. I don't get the reason. it prints the table heading but doesn't print the data.

User adds a new patient at first. Then assigns them to a hospital. Then, If I load hospital data, They should appear there.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int allhospitalsdata[4][3] = {{1,3,0},{2,200,0},{3,300,0},{4,400,0}}; //assumed data about hospitals
char **ptrsptr;
int patientsnum;

void choosetask ();
void newpatient ();
int ispatientsaved (char *name);
int assignpatient (char *name, int hospitalid);
void loadhospitaldata (int hospitalid);

int main()
{
   choosetask();
   return 0;
}

void choosetask()
{
   //some code to choose a function to call
   // if user chooses to load a hospital data, do this:

    int hospitalid;
    char name [51];
    int tasknumber;
    int x;

   printf ("\nChoose a task to perform:\n 1- Insert the data of a new patient.\n 2- Assign a patient to a hospital.\n 3- Load a hospital patients data.\n\nWrite its number to go: ");
    scanf ("%d", &tasknumber);

    switch (tasknumber)
    {
    case 1:
        newpatient ();
        break;


    case 2:
        printf ("\nEnter the patient name, please: ");
        scanf ("%50s", name);
        x=ispatientsaved(name);
        if(x==0)
        {
            printf ("Patient does not exist. Add them first, Please.\n");
            break;
        }
        printf ("Enter the hospital ID you want to assign the patient to: ");
        scanf ("%1d", &hospitalid);
        if (!((hospitalid==1)||(hospitalid==2)||(hospitalid==3)||(hospitalid==4)))
        {
            printf ("Hospital does not exist.\n");
            break;
        }
        x=assignpatient (name, hospitalid);
        if (!(x==1))
        {
          printf("Patient does not exist.");
        }
        break;

    case 3:
        printf ("\nEnter the hospital ID, please: ");
        scanf ("%1d", &hospitalid);
        if (!((hospitalid==1)||(hospitalid==2)||(hospitalid==3)||(hospitalid==4)))
        {
            printf ("Hospital does not exist.\n");
            break;
        }
        loadhospitaldata (hospitalid);
        break;
}
choosetask();
}

void newpatient ()
{
  char name[51];
  int age=0;
  char agestr[3];
  char infectiondate [11];
  char address[51];
  char *patientptr;
  char **newptr;

  printf("\nEnter the patient name (50 characters at maximum): ");
  scanf ("%50s", name);

  if (ispatientsaved (name) == 1)
    {
        printf ("patient already exists.\n");
        return;
    }

  patientsnum ++;

  newptr = (char**) realloc(ptrsptr, patientsnum*sizeof(char *));
  if (newptr) ptrsptr = newptr;
  else
  {
    patientsnum --;
    printf ("Not enough memory.\n");
    return;
  }

  patientptr = (char*) calloc (118, sizeof (char)); // allocation after being sure patient doesn't exist
  if (!patientptr)
  {
    patientsnum --;
    printf ("Not enough memory.\n");
    return;
  }

  strcpy(patientptr, name);

  printf("Enter the patient age: ");
  scanf ("%d", &age);
  sprintf (agestr, "%2d", age);
  strcpy((patientptr + 51),agestr);

  printf("Enter the patient date of infection (in form of dd/mm/year): ");
  scanf ("%10s", infectiondate);
  strcpy((patientptr + 54),infectiondate);

  printf("Enter the patient address (50 characters at maximum): ");
  scanf ("%50s", address);
  strcpy((patientptr + 65),address);

  *(ptrsptr+patientsnum-1) = patientptr;

  printf ("Patient added succesfully.\n");
}

int ispatientsaved (char *name)
{
  char tryname[51];

  for (int i=0; i<patientsnum; i++)
  {
      for (int j=0; j<51; j++)
      {
          tryname[j]=*(*(ptrsptr+i)+j);
      }
      if (strcmp(tryname, name)==0)
      {
        return 1;
        break;
      }
  }
  return 0;
}

int assignpatient (char *name, int hospitalid)
{
 char hospitalidstr[2];
 char tryname[51];

  if (allhospitalsdata[hospitalid-1][2]<allhospitalsdata[hospitalid-1][1])
  {
    sprintf (hospitalidstr, "%2d", hospitalid);
    for (int i=0; i<patientsnum; i++)
    {
      for (int j=0; j<51; j++)
      {
          tryname[j]=*(*(ptrsptr+i)+j);
      }
      if (strcmp(tryname, name)==0)
      {
        strcpy((*(ptrsptr+i)+116),hospitalidstr);
        allhospitalsdata[hospitalid-1][2]++;
        printf ("Patient assigned successfully to hospital #%d.\n", hospitalid);
        return 1;
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
      printf ("This hospital is full. Choose another one, please: ");
      scanf ("%1d", &hospitalid);
      assignpatient (name,hospitalid);
  }
}

void loadhospitaldata (int hospitalid)
{
  int tryid;
  char tryidstr[2];

  //print the table first cells
  printf ("\nname\t\t\t\t\t\t\tage\t date of infection   address");

  //for each patient, get his hospitalid. If it equlas the passed one, load and print his data.
  for (int i=0; i<patientsnum; i++)
    {
      for (int j=116; j<118; j++)
      {
        tryidstr[j-116]=*(*(ptrsptr+i)+j);
      }
      tryid = atoi(tryidstr);
      if (tryid==hospitalid)
      {
        char name[51];
        char agestr[3];
        char infectiondate [11];
        char address[51];

        for (int j=0; j<51; i++)
        {
           name[j]=*(*(ptrsptr+i)+j);
        }

        for (int j=0; j<3; i++)
        {
            agestr[j]=*(*(ptrsptr+i)+j+51);
        }

        for (int j=0; j<11; i++)
        {
           infectiondate[j]=*(*(ptrsptr+i)+j+54);
        }

        for (int j=0; j<51; i++)
        {
            address[j]=*(*(ptrsptr+i)+j+65);
        }

        printf("%50s\t  %2s\t  %10s\t  %50s",name,agestr,infectiondate,address);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: the double bar is for or logical operator and the single one is for bitwise operator.

Comment: There are 2 mistakes in the code...
First, you should not use break inside an `if` statement. It should be used in a loop or a switch case...
Second, the variable `patientsnum` is not assigned any value.

Comment: @RishabhHardas IF is in switch case and I removed that to be concise, but forgot the break. Patientsnum gets its value from another function.

Comment: Can you post a minimum working example ?

Comment: @RishabhHardas Here is something that should work. I think the error may be while adding or assigning the patient or while loading the data. The code is long, but I provided a quick explanation to help.

Comment: Does not compile.

Comment: Your `main` function only calls `choosetask` once. When the program exits, any data you entered will have gone away.

Comment: @IanAbbott I call `choosetask` from within it to recall it again and again after finishing a task.

Comment: @RishabhHardas Try now,please. This should compile

Comment: learn to use your debugger

Comment: Calling `choosetask` at the end of `choosetask` relies on the compiler optimizing the tail recursion to a simple loop. If the compiler doesn't do that, it will gradually eat more of the stack at each recursive call. It would be better to actually use a loop to avoid that, since there is no reason why the function has to be recursive.